# Is is a good approach to limit the size of JWT this way?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Some API sites i used have relatively small token sizes but when i use jwt i get token in the size of more than 200. I am generatingtokens for session management using JWT as

```
 const token_generated = (jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'your_jwt_secret'));
 const token=token_generated.substr(token_generated.length-15,15);
```

I am doing so as the size of JWT generated is really large. Is this a good approach to handle this or are there any methods available in jwt to limit token sizes

Comment: The reason is JWT is long because it contain the hash , the data and algorithm detail. You might be talking about some website which uses like some asymmetric tokens. i think you just can't take the part of the JWT and rebuild it again.

Comment: ok that makes sense thanks.